# Is it safe to lock my computer during program installation?

Tags: windows, installation, lock-screen

While installing [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/) on my office PC, I was called away for a company meeting and needed to leave my workstation unattended.

Company policy says that we should lock our screens with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> before leaving a computer unattended, but I'm not sure whether [interrupting an in-progress installation](http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/discussions/windows-installation-interrupted-by-power-failure-wont-boot/) is the best idea.

**Is it safe to lock my computer before a program has finished installing?**

[image: Git Installation 71%]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, it's safe.**

Locking your desktop doesn't interrupt anything, it just... locks your desktop :)

Underneath the lock screen, the PC is working just like it would while being unlocked.